# POST PHP error via Ajax on unsuccessful login

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap Alert to be shown when a user could not be logged in.

To do this, I am using Ajax (jQuery) and POSTing the error upon redirect, to the script on my index.php

Here is the PHP on login.php:

```
$message = "Your Email or Password combination were incorrect. Please try again.";
echo json_encode($message);
header('Location: /');
```

and my jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: "message",
            success: function (response) {
                var message = jQuery.parseJSON(message);
                $('#alert').text(message);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
User tries to log in (and fails)
Redirected to home page (as my login form is in the header)
Error alert is shown, with the $message content as the error text.
```

When I make an incorrect login (to trigger the error) I get

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I'm still a beginner with jQuery, and have tried to follow other examples which is why my code probably doesn't make sense (and why it isn't working).

I'm using firebug on Firefox to debug the jQuery.

Thanks for your time

Comment: What script is your ajax function calling? Is it `login.php`?

Comment: I think this (jQuery.parseJSON(message);) would give an error if message does not exist. What you probably want to work on is the ```response``` variable Also, you php ajax code should just echo out your expected response, and not do a header redirect

Comment: Yes, my ajax function is calling login.php

Comment: The error in my firebug console is saying two variables are not set (email and password used to login) however I only want to show $message if the variable is set. Is this something I can do in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error lies in a misunderstanding of what the line: `$(this).attr('action')`  is doing in your `$.ajax` call.

When I run your code the function works perfectly... except that it loads the current page! Which is exactly what you told it to do. Sending `$(this).attr('action')` in the `url:` parameter just told your ajax function to load the current page. As the current page has `javascript` and presumably `HTML` defined in it the response is not valid `JSON`.

What you want to do is change:

```
url: $(this).attr('action'),
```

To:

```
url: 'path/to/login.php',
```

Comment: When I change it to that, in firebug the response is "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" which are the undefined login variables to my script, as I have not tried to login. When I use an incorrect login, it echoes the $message variable on my login.php page, instead of redirecting to my index.php

Comment: @PublicDisplayName Are you expecting the script loaded by your ajax call to redirect the user?

Comment: What I want to happen is, the user fills in the form, submits the form and the data is sent to my login.php script. From there, the login credentials don't match up, which fails passwordverify(). In my else statement, the error message is stored in $message variable, the user is redirected to my index page and the contents of $message are echoed in my alert box to let them know the login failed.

Answer (score 0):

i change type and remove comma
make a json request and chage success to done

**try this**

```js
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: "message",
      dataType: "json"}).done(function () {
      var message = jQuery.parseJSON(message);
      $('#alert').text(message);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Used what you said, however has no action, no errors in firebug log either